# How can I aggregate QS data from different sources on one and unique dashboard?

Tags: sensors, communication, mobile-applications, monitoring, smart-watches

I would like to automatically aggregate QS data, biofeedback data and neurofeedback data from different applications into one dashboard.

Data is collected from; Gear S2, Withings body scale, Withings blood pressure, Wahoo TICKR X, Lumolift, Under Armor Gemini 2.1 Record equipped, Muse Headband, Dexcomm blood glucose.

I'm looking for a simple dashboard for now, but picture S Health and Daytum as UI/UX inspiration.

Hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I suspect that there isn't anything that already exists already to aggregate the data and display it nicely. There are probably a few ways of exporting data into a custom application though; would you be  interested in a solution where you would connect the dashboard code yourself? Also, could you clarify why S Health doesn't fit your needs so it's a little bit clearer for us?

Comment: Can you add product references or describe the way you collect the data from these devices?

Comment: Are you looking to use the APIs provided by each vendor to aggregate the data in your own product, or looking for a 3rd party who already provides this? Do the vendors all provide activity feeds, or will you need to negotiate with them?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the welcoming and the response ! 
Aurora0001, I am happy to hear more about how can connect the dashboard code myself. I  wonder if I need any deep programming skills to get my own simpler version of S health? 

Bench Kaulics, I am not sure what do you mean by product references. Can you please define?

Sean Houlihane, Yes you got the idea ! Do I need the authorization of each products to use their APIs? And what if the product do not have an API, how can I get the data to synch in my product (dashboard)?

Thank you for your time,

Looking forward to your response,

Comment: @Idiot_Savant: Just so you know, if you want to reply it's best to do it in separate comments, and ping each user with `@username`, e.g. `@Aurora0001: your message here`. If you do that, the user you ping will get a notification, so they know you've replied (you cannot ping multiple users in one comment though). I'll do a bit of research for you and try to answer later today if I can.

Comment: @Idiot_Savant Its best if you edit your question to add detail, this makes it easier for new readers to understand the whole thing. This is how you ought to respond where you want to show the examples that you posted in questions below.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear since the user persistently refuses to edit the question.

Comment: @Idiot_Savant Not sure if you saw the comment on your previous post—if you have a new question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You also may want to check the [tour]; Stack Exchange isn't like your regular forum where you add to a 'thread' when you want updates—instead, try to ask a single question in each post. You can add a link to this question in your new question, though. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 4):

It probably won't come as a surprise to you, but it doesn't seem like there are any pre-existing solutions which can link your devices together. However, since you said you were interested in custom-built solutions, you might be able to get close to what you want.

I did a bit of research into your devices to see if they had open APIs you could take advantage of. Unfortunately, not all the devices you listed are open - the Samsung Gear uses S Health, and I could only find APIs to *import* data into S Health, not get it back out into your own application. The Wahoo doesn't seem to have a simple web API, and nor does the Muse and Dexcom monitor. The rest of the devices **do** have nice APIs (which I've listed below).

### Data Sources

- [Withings API](http://oauth.withings.com/api/doc)
- [Lumo API](https://dev.lumobodytech.com/docs/activities.html)
- [Under Armour API](https://developer.underarmour.com/docs)

### Creating a Dashboard

This really depends on your technical ability with programming. If you're not at all familiar with programming, your best bet would be some sort of spreadsheet software such as Excel or Google Sheets.

Google Sheets supports basic scripting, and [someone has developed a way to make JSON requests (the type of request needed to communicate with the APIs I listed)](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.knkb1smbc). You could also read [*Is it possible to send HTTP request from inside Google docs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917189/is-it-possible-to-send-http-request-from-inside-google-docs) on Stack Overflow for more context here.

Each API will have requirements on how to authenticate (for example, [Withings](http://oauth.withings.com/api) uses OAuth), which you'll have to factor in when making your requests. It's probably worth spending some time getting familiar with the scripting needed to connect to these APIs (Google Apps uses JavaScript primarily); Google's [*Overview of Google Apps Script*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) will probably help a lot here.

Once you get the data imported into your spreadsheet, it should be relatively straightforward to make a dashboard out of the data, and won't require much special knowledge. You'll also get complete design control for what you want to show, which is great, although it will obviously still be a spreadsheet.

If you need any more specific guidance, you can always ask a more specific question (programming questions can also be asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)). Good luck!

---

In responses to your questions that you asked in an answer:

> Assuming that I know a bit about programming, how realistic reverse engineering would be in making an API for the Gear, Muse and Dexcom monitor? What would be the simplest approach to do so?

Probably not particularly easy; I would contact the manufacturers (as suggested by Sean Houlihane in the comments).

> Any idea on how can I get similar results as above? Do I have to design the interface in Photoshop first and then create an HTML page to import my data from Google Sheet or AM I getting it wrong?

It depends on your approach. If you're able to design it in HTML, go ahead and do that, then use a framework like jQuery, Angular or ReactJS to connect your UI to the APIs.

> I might have misunderstood but it does not seem like Google Sheets nor Excel enable auto synch for the devices. It sounds like I have to enter the data manually...

That's true, you would have to manually rerun the request in Google Sheets. If you used a HTML page like I mentioned in response to the last question, that wouldn't be a problem as data would have to be fetched new each time from the API.

You could either go the HTML route **or** the Google Sheets route; if you're able, the HTML method would work a lot better and give you more flexibility.