# Implementing Personal Metrics into Dubli - Bootstrapping responsive Admin Web applications with AngularJS

Tags: web-services

I am building a website to monitor my personal metrics using Dubli - Bootstrapping responsive Admin Web applications with AngularJS.

However I have issue figure out how can I change some of the pre existing widgets to add my own to monitor/track my personal metrics like health/wellness, biometrics, biological and online data such as emails, twitter, Facebook, or browser history onto the dashboard.

Thanks for your time

Previous thread: [How can I aggregate QS data from different sources on one and unique dashboard?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/940/how-can-i-aggregate-qs-data-from-different-sources-on-one-and-unique-dashboard?noredirect=1#comment2092_940)

Comment: Needs some more context. I search for the words here, and I get what looks like meaningless link spam.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could include the links to things like Dubli so it's clearer what you're talking about. Has anything that you've tried so far not worked? It'd be useful if you list everything you've done so far, so we don't recommend that you do something that won't work. Don't forget to [edit], which will automatically send your post to the reopening queue.